# How do I correctly implement LINQ statement 'from x in collection'?

Tags: c#, linq

I made a simple class for a basic database to test my LINQ query that I copied from Microsoft's help center out but got an error that is baffling me.  The error said x does not exist in the current context.

class example:

```
public class Student
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<int> Scores;

    List<Student> students = new List<Student> {
        new Student {First="Svetlana", Last="Omelchenko", ID=111, Scores= new List<int> {97, 92, 81, 60}},
        new Student {First="Claire", Last="O'Donnell", ID=112, Scores= new List<int> {75, 84, 91, 39}},
        new Student {First="Sven", Last="Mortensen", ID=113, Scores= new List<int> {88, 94, 65, 91}},
        new Student {First="Cesar", Last="Garcia", ID=114, Scores= new List<int> {97, 89, 85, 82}},
        new Student {First="Debra", Last="Garcia", ID=115, Scores= new List<int> {35, 72, 91, 70}},
        new Student {First="Fadi", Last="Fakhouri", ID=116, Scores= new List<int> {99, 86, 90, 94}},
        new Student {First="Hanying", Last="Feng", ID=117, Scores= new List<int> {93, 92, 80, 87}},
        new Student {First="Hugo", Last="Garcia", ID=118, Scores= new List<int> {92, 90, 83, 78}},
        new Student {First="Lance", Last="Tucker", ID=119, Scores= new List<int> {68, 79, 88, 92}},
        new Student {First="Terry", Last="Adams", ID=120, Scores= new List<int> {99, 82, 81, 79}},
        new Student {First="Eugene", Last="Zabokritski", ID=121, Scores= new List<int> {96, 85, 91, 60}},
        new Student {First="Michael", Last="Tucker", ID=122, Scores= new List<int> {94, 92, 91, 91} }
    };
}
```

query statement:

```
  IEnumerable<Student> studentQuery = 
            from student in **students** this is the error that the compiler told me 'does not exist in the current context'
            where student.Scores[0] > 90
            select student;
```

Comment: Is the query inside the Student class? Because the list `students` is private.

Comment: class inside calling to same class constructor goes to infinite.

Answer (score 1):

I belive you want to have like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<int> Scores;
}

List<Student> students = new List<Student> {
    new Student {First="Svetlana", Last="Omelchenko", ID=111, Scores= new List<int> {97, 92, 81, 60}},
    new Student {First="Claire", Last="O'Donnell", ID=112, Scores= new List<int> {75, 84, 91, 39}},
    new Student {First="Sven", Last="Mortensen", ID=113, Scores= new List<int> {88, 94, 65, 91}},
    new Student {First="Cesar", Last="Garcia", ID=114, Scores= new List<int> {97, 89, 85, 82}},
    new Student {First="Debra", Last="Garcia", ID=115, Scores= new List<int> {35, 72, 91, 70}},
    new Student {First="Fadi", Last="Fakhouri", ID=116, Scores= new List<int> {99, 86, 90, 94}},
    new Student {First="Hanying", Last="Feng", ID=117, Scores= new List<int> {93, 92, 80, 87}},
    new Student {First="Hugo", Last="Garcia", ID=118, Scores= new List<int> {92, 90, 83, 78}},
    new Student {First="Lance", Last="Tucker", ID=119, Scores= new List<int> {68, 79, 88, 92}},
    new Student {First="Terry", Last="Adams", ID=120, Scores= new List<int> {99, 82, 81, 79}},
    new Student {First="Eugene", Last="Zabokritski", ID=121, Scores= new List<int> {96, 85, 91, 60}},
    new Student {First="Michael", Last="Tucker", ID=122, Scores= new List<int> {94, 92, 91, 91} }
};

IEnumerable<Student> studentQuery = 
        from student in students
        where student.Scores[0] > 90
        select student;
```